# Is this a good idiom for passing optional/NULL shared_ptr parameters?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I'm new to shared_ptrs and have been struggling with the right way to handle "optional" pointer arguments. That is, how best to pass pointer arguments to a method, any of which might be NULL on any given invocation. Here's a simplified example using raw pointers:

```
class Obj {
   SomeType *ptrA;
   SomeType *ptrB;
   ...
   void method(SomeType* a, SomeType* b) {
      ptrA = a;
      ptrB = b;
   }
}
```

Now switch to shared_ptrs:

```
class Obj {
   shared_ptr<SomeType> ptrA;
   shared_ptr<SomeType> ptrB;

   // Option 1: pointers to shared pointers:

   void method1(shared_ptr<SomeType>* a, shared_ptr<SomeType>* b) {
      if (a) ptrA = *a;
      else   ptrA.reset();
      // repeat for b
   }

   // Option 2: pass empty shared_ptrs as analog for NULL

   void method2(shared_ptr<SomeType> a, shared_ptr<SomeType> b) {
      ptrA = a;
      ptrB = b;
   }
}
```

method1 takes pointers to shared_ptrs so callers can pass NULL and you can easily declare arguments with a default value of NULL. However, the logic gets a bit messy and using pointers to shared_ptrs just seems wrong.

method2 requires that the caller create temporary empty shared_ptrs for any "NULL" arguments. That's cumbersome and obscure at best.

Is method1 the best way? Is there a better way? Have I completely missed the boat here?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your argument. What's cumbersome and obscure about passing a temporary empty `shared_ptr`? On the other hand isn't asking `Obj` to release one of its pointers completely different operation to asking it to shared ownership of a new object? If so, why not have different functions for these different operations then the caller can use a completely simple and clear function call in both cases?

Comment: Take a look at Boost.optional for this purpose.

Comment: @CharlesBailey It seems to me that something like method(shared_ptr<SomeType>(), shared_ptr<SomeType>()) is substantially less readable, at a glance, than method(NULL, NULL). And if I understand things, you really should use explicit temporaries which makes it even worse (I think). You're right about set vs clear, but in some cases it's more appropriate to pass all arguments into a single method rather than have indivdual setters/getters.

Comment: I don't think anyone familiar with C++ will find `shared_ptr<SomeType>()` at all unreadable and at least the type of object being passed is obvious. I don't understand your comment about explicit temporaries. What's not explicit enough about `shared_ptr<SomeType>()`?

Comment: @CharlesBailey Regarding readability... fair enough. Regarding temporaries, the best practices at Boost specifically state that you should avoid constructing temporary shared_ptrs as function arguments. Does this not apply to empty shared_ptrs? At risk of committing premature optimization, constructing empty shared_ptrs just to indicate non-existence seems like the long way around the barn.

Comment: Unrelated: it might be better to pass const reference to the shared pointer in the `method2`. Avoiding one interlocked increment and all that.

Comment: @dschultz You shouldn't pass temporary `shared_ptr`s to functions **when they contain dynamically allocated objects**, because they can leak the pointer in some circumstances. There is no such concern for empty `shared_ptr`s.

Comment: @dschultz: Judging by http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm, the problem they're referring to isn't an issue for empty shared_ptrs.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks for that tip. Yet another intriguing bit of Boost that I'm unfamiliar with. It's not immediately obvious to me how that helps in this particular case, other than just being another possible approach. An empty shared_ptr already embodies the notion of null-ness that boost::optional imbues on other types so I'm not sure what it would add.

Comment: @dschultz: A shared pointer has shared ownership semantics; Boost.optional does not. Choose whichever reflects your needs better. (Note that `shared_ptr` is more expensive.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with passing a null shared pointer. In fact, a null shared pointer is an actual [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern), which means that it's designed exactly for those kinds of uses.